# Sublime Text 3 : How to remove Channel JSON URL

Tags: sublimetext3, text-editor, package-control

How to remove 'Channel JSON URL' from being permanently placed at the bottom of my sublime text editor.

[image]

After installing package control I noticed this pinned to the bottom of the sublime

Comment: Does it go away if you hit escape once or twice? Does it reappear after you restart the program? From your image, it looks like you selected the Remove Channel option from Package Control, and the box at the bottom is simply waiting for input from you as to which channel to remove.

Comment: Yap that was it, if you want to post that as an answer I can flag this as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your image, it looks like you (accidentally?) selected the Remove Channel option from Package Control, and the box at the bottom is simply waiting for input from you as to which channel to remove. To get rid of it, just hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>.